# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number1' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am getting an error in line 2 saying that i have an unboundLocal error. can anyone explain to me how to fix this?

```
 def main():
            number1=getNumber1(number1)
            number2=getNumber2(number2)
            userIntro=''
            printInfo=0.0
            answer=0.0
    #intro module welcomes the user
        def userIntro():
            print('hello welcome to my maximum value calculator')
            print('today we will evaluate two number and display the greater one')
    #this module gets the value of number1
        def getNumber1(number1):
            number1=print(input('Enter the value of number1'))
            return (getNumber1)
    #this module gets the value of number2    
        def getnumber2(number2):
            number2=print(input('Enter the value of number2'))
            return (getNumber2)
    #this module takes the values of number1,number2 and displays the greater value    
        def printInfo(number1,number2,answer):
            answer=max(number1,number2)
            return (answer)
        main()
```

Comment: `number1=getNumber1(number1)
            number2=getNumber2(number2)` you are trying to create and pass the variables to the function at the same time?

Comment: What do you expect the first two lines in main to do? Think about what you're doing there, and your error will become clear. Also, there are other errors in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`number1` isn't defined until you create it - you can't pass it to another function while defining it. Seems like you need a simpler function that gets the **name** you want to assign to:

```
def main():
    number1 = getNumber('number1')
    number2 = getNumber('number2')

def getNumber(name):
    return input('Enter the value of ' + name))
```

Comment: i seem to have fixed the beginning part of my code but i can't seem to get the maximum amount to display, is printInfo module written correctly? i have never used the "max" function so this is all new to me.